# Does feast support postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, feast

Does Feast https://feast.dev support postgresql as data-ingestion. In my previous work load, I just downloaded data every second and insert into postgresql. if not, which database shall i use so that it would be the easiest migration for me? I’m basically building financial model feature store….

Answer (score 2):

Postgres supported as Registry, Online store, and Offline store is now available officially in feast version [0.21.0](https://github.com/feast-dev/feast/compare/v0.20.0...v0.21.0).

Refer:
https://github.com/feast-dev/feast/releases

Answer (score 1):

They have good documentation on how to create new [providers](https://docs.feast.dev/how-to-guides/creating-a-custom-provider), and [online](https://docs.feast.dev/how-to-guides/adding-support-for-a-new-online-store) and [offline](https://docs.feast.dev/how-to-guides/adding-a-new-offline-store) stores.

I wanted to connect Feast to postgres so I wrote this: [feast-postgres](https://github.com/nossrannug/feast-postgres)

Maybe not something you would want to use in production right away since I haven't done any testing, but nothing that says we can't get there :)

Comment: I see config implementation(with connection details in postgres_config.py) and the offlinestore class(as postgres.py). Don't we require to configure any postgres driver anywhere?  I am trying to understand better, since I am looking for a Snowflake DB implementation as offline store. It looks Feast is predominantly used only for Redshift/DynamoDb/Bigquery/Datastore in focus primarily.

Answer (score 1):

Support for postgresql is on their [roadmap](https://docs.feast.dev/roadmap) which contains the functionality that contributors are planning to develop for Feast.

(Not sure if [Gunnarsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957738/gunnarsi) (other answer here) is involved there or it's a separate effort.)

Comment: Extended my sentence.